# Using gulp scripts to minify js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gulp

So for some reason, I'm having some problems with my gulp scripts where `gulp scripts` won't write the appropriate js to the bundled file.

So I have the following folder structure:

```
theme/  
- dist/  
--- css/
----- bundle.css
--- js  
----- bundle.js
- src/  
--- scss/  
----- bundle.scss
--- js/  
----- bundle.js
----- components/  
------- test.js
```

Here is the `gulp styles` task which works perfect - What it does is that it takes all of the contents inside `src/scss/` and bundles it and exports it to `dist/css/bundle.css`.

```
export const styles = () => {
    return src(['src/scss/bundle.scss', 'src/scss/admin.scss', 'src/scss/bulmapress.scss'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(cleanCss({compatibility:'ie8'})
        .pipe(dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(server.stream());
}
```

My `src/scss/bundle.scss` file has the following:

```
@import "components/header";
@import "components/footer";
```

Here is the task that I have for `gulp scripts` where once I run the task, it doesn't compile the content inside `src/js/components` etc.. it compiled things that are inside `src/js/bundle.js` which is just a storage component to define `import "components/test"`. Here is the task:

```
export const scripts = () => {
    return src(['src/js/bundle.js'])
        .pipe(dest('dist/js'));
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if this is natural behavior? What might be a better alternative to do this? Below is the full `gulpfile.babel.js` if anyone wants to check it out.

Would it be better for js to not be bundled into `bundle.js` and just be minimized into it's own separate file?

```js
import { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } from 'gulp'; //import { src, dest, watch, series, parallel } from 'gulp';
import yargs from 'yargs';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import cleanCss from 'gulp-clean-css';
import gulpif from 'gulp-if';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin';
import del from 'del';
import browserSync from "browser-sync";
import zip from "gulp-zip";
import info from "./package.json";
import replace from "gulp-replace";

const PRODUCTION = yargs.argv.prod;
const server = browserSync.create();

export const serve = done => {
    server.init({
        proxy: "http://localhost:8888/starter"
    });
    done();
};
export const reload = done => {
    server.reload();
    done();
};
export const styles = () => {
    return src(['src/scss/bundle.scss', 'src/scss/admin.scss', 'src/scss/bulmapress.scss'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(cleanCss({compatibility:'ie8'})
        .pipe(dest('dist/css'))
        .pipe(server.stream());
}
export const scripts = () => {
    return src(['src/js/bundle.js'])
        .pipe(dest('dist/js'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transpile ES6 code to ES5 code using gulp-babel before you do uglification or minification.

Read this article about gulp tasks to understand how gulp works:
https://medium.com/@sudoanushil/how-to-write-gulp-tasks-ce1b1b7a7e81